# Crating a cross reference Tab from a messy .csv

Tags: python, plot, tabs, cross-reference

I have csv which associates each entry with several tags (variable number and variable order) and I would like to create a tab as the one below, where each entry indicates with an 'x' which tag they are connected to:

[image: cross reference tab]

I've been trying with several approaches, and I even tried plotting these datas, but with no result.

```
import pandas as pd

id_df = pd.read_csv('pathToCsv')

id_df.set_index('Key', inplace=True)
id_df.sort_values
id_df.plot(x="Manual Tag 1", y="Manual Tag 2", kind="scatter")
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But i'm completely stuck ( probablay due to fatigue as well). I'm tuck and I do't know how to move.